# what is the javascript internal data structure?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, hashing

Consider a basic js object:

```
var obj={x:1,y:'2'};
```

Is this stored internally as a hashtable or does js use a different mechanism for key value pairs? If they are hash tables does anyone know how they handle collisions?

Comment: Its likely up to the various engine as to how the internals are represented.  Beyond that, it doesn't appear to say in the [ECMA definition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"javascript internal" doesn't really mean anything, as far as I know, such thing isn't specified for Javascript.

For some Javascript *engine* or *interpreter*, the internal representation can be any number of things, whatever works for any given situation.

For long-lived objects of indeterminate lifetime, it's most likely a hash table, but also a list (or whatever) of property names in natural ("alphabetical") sorted order probably exists at least temporarily.

Arrays, as much as they exist in Javascript, probably also have a custom, optimized internal data structure, which may support faster indexed access than going through creating a hash table hash.

And then a JS engine doing JIT might for example see that the object is never used for anything, in which case that object can be *nothing* internally, the instance is just optimized away and never actually created.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the implementation.

From v8/src/objects.h (Chrome's V8):

```
// Inheritance hierarchy:
// - MaybeObject    (an object or a failure)
//   - Failure      (immediate for marking failed operation)
//   - Object
//     - Smi          (immediate small integer)
//     - HeapObject   (superclass for everything allocated in the heap)
//       - JSReceiver  (suitable for property access)
//         - JSObject
//           - JSArray
//           - JSArrayBuffer
//           - JSArrayBufferView
//             - JSTypedArray
//             - JSDataView
//           - JSSet
//           - JSMap
//           - JSSetIterator
//           - JSMapIterator
//           - JSWeakCollection
//             - JSWeakMap
//             - JSWeakSet
//           - JSRegExp
//           - JSFunction
//           - JSGeneratorObject
//           - JSModule
//           - GlobalObject
//             - JSGlobalObject
//             - JSBuiltinsObject
//           - JSGlobalProxy
//           - JSValue
//             - JSDate
//           - JSMessageObject
//         - JSProxy
//           - JSFunctionProxy
//       - FixedArrayBase
//         - ByteArray
//         - FixedArray
//           - DescriptorArray
//           - HashTable
//             - Dictionary
//             - StringTable
//             - CompilationCacheTable
//             - CodeCacheHashTable
//             - MapCache
//           - OrderedHashTable
//             - OrderedHashSet
//             - OrderedHashMap
//           - Context
//           - JSFunctionResultCache
//           - ScopeInfo
//           - TransitionArray
//         - FixedDoubleArray
//         - ExternalArray
//           - ExternalUint8ClampedArray
//           - ExternalInt8Array
//           - ExternalUint8Array
//           - ExternalInt16Array
//           - ExternalUint16Array
//           - ExternalInt32Array
//           - ExternalUint32Array
//           - ExternalFloat32Array
//       - Name
//         - String
//           - SeqString
//             - SeqOneByteString
//             - SeqTwoByteString
//           - SlicedString
//           - ConsString
//           - ExternalString
//             - ExternalAsciiString
//             - ExternalTwoByteString
//           - InternalizedString
//             - SeqInternalizedString
//               - SeqOneByteInternalizedString
//               - SeqTwoByteInternalizedString
//             - ConsInternalizedString
//             - ExternalInternalizedString
//               - ExternalAsciiInternalizedString
//               - ExternalTwoByteInternalizedString
//         - Symbol
//       - HeapNumber
//       - Cell
//         - PropertyCell
//       - Code
//       - Map
//       - Oddball
//       - Foreign
//       - SharedFunctionInfo
//       - Struct
//         - Box
//         - DeclaredAccessorDescriptor
//         - AccessorInfo
//           - DeclaredAccessorInfo
//           - ExecutableAccessorInfo
//         - AccessorPair
//         - AccessCheckInfo
//         - InterceptorInfo
//         - CallHandlerInfo
//         - TemplateInfo
//           - FunctionTemplateInfo
//           - ObjectTemplateInfo
//         - Script
//         - SignatureInfo
//         - TypeSwitchInfo
//         - DebugInfo
//         - BreakPointInfo
//         - CodeCache
//
// Formats of Object*:
//  Smi:        [31 bit signed int] 0
//  HeapObject: [32 bit direct pointer] (4 byte aligned) | 01
//  Failure:    [30 bit signed int] 11
```

Can't say for certain but I'd imagine it's a `JSMap` considering a `JSReceiver` is  "suitable for property access".

From mozjs-24.2.0/js/src/jsobj.h (Firefox's SpiderMonkey):

```
/*
 * JS object definitions.
 *
 * A JS object consists of a possibly-shared object descriptor containing
 * ordered property names, called the map; and a dense vector of property
 * values, called slots.  The map/slot pointer pair is GC'ed, while the map
 * is reference counted and the slot vector is malloc'ed.
 */
```

Looks like a map again.

If you're really curious you might want to check out the source yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The ECMAScript specification does not prescribe any particular implementation strategy. And why would it? Having different engines compete for performance using different implementation strategies is a Good Thing™.